# Posting large amount of content serves 403 error

Tags: error, long-content

Is there a content limit/length for channels? If so, can the limit be removed?

**Reason I ask:**

When posting a large amount of content (approx 12,700 characters) in a channel (blog) as soon as I submit I get served a 403 Forbidden screen: http://screencast.com/t/9vPuJo4hup6

However, if I post a small amount of content (a couple of paragraphs) and submit there are no problems.

I tested this further by posting the large amount of content paragraph by paragraph and submitting after each one (paragraph). This process was successful up until I reached a certain amount of content and then I was served the 403 again.

It appears that there is some sort of content limit in channels?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Try this: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/7134/150

Comment: Might also be a mod_security thing. Ask your host whether that's enabled and if they can either disable it or add an exception.

Comment: @Low, is there any good reason not to ask the host to disable mod_security for my account? (just wondering). Thanks for both of your feedback.

Comment: @Low, Have just heard back from our host saying it was indeed the mod_security that was preventing us from posting large amount of content (blog posts). They have disabled mod_security and all seems to be working fine now (thanks!). One last question though - by disabling mod_security does that make our site vulnerable to hackers/attacks? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not entirely versed in mod_security, but from my experience, it's more of a nuisance than a benefit. I don't really know the ramifications, if there are any. I *think* it doesn't matter all that much. I'll also add a proper answer to your Q so you can mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: @Dan Your host should have set a mod_sec rule up for that one domain rather than disable mod_security. Mod Security does a lot of good stuff imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, getting 404 or 403 errors after submitting a form is because of a `mod_security` setting in Apache on the server. This isn't something EE can influence or circumvent, really.

You can try to add this to your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

However, this could result in an error 500 (Internal Server Error) if you're not allowed to turn the SecFilterEngine off. If that's the case, ask your host if `mod_security` is enabled and if they could disable it. They could also add one or more exceptions to the `mod_security` settings for your site instead of disabling it completely.